# ClassNotFoundException on com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

I try to add to my app Google Tag Manger referrer tracker. I use this documentation: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/ua

And add to my Maniferst below code:

```
<service android:name="com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerService" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

now using docs for testing and verification: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

I sent via adb

```
echo 'am broadcast \
    -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER \
    -n "pl.my.app/com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver" \
    --es "referrer" \
      "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"; \
    exit' | ./adb shell
```

And I get crash in my app:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/pl.my.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/pl.my.app-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1431)
>                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/pl.my.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/pl.my.app-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                              at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2719)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1431) 
>                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
>                                                           Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver
>                                                              at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                              at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                              at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                   ... 10 more
>                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Any idea what going on?

I guess that I should add something in gladle.  I think that

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.4.0'
```

is not enough.

Comment: Did you try to add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` in your gradle file?

Comment: I think the class is: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.InstallReferrerService and 
com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver

Comment: @fiddler i tried  but not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TagManager is content in `play-services-analytics`

Add this in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
```

As mention in google documentation, your `Manifest` should content this :

```
<!-- Used for install referrer tracking-->
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.InstallReferrerService" />
<receiver
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver"
  android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

your package name seem wrong :`com.google.tagmanager.InstallReferrerService`

Answer (score 0):

I had an error like this in my `react-native` app.

change this part of `android\app\build.gradle` file:

Update the previous `:react-native-google-analytics-bridge` code like this:

```
implementation(project(":react-native-google-analytics-bridge"),  {
  exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
})
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
```

and then change your `firebase` code like this:

```
...
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
...
```

And in `android\gradle.properties` at the bottom of file add

```
firebaseCoreVersion=16.0.8
firebaseMessagingVersion=17.6.0
```